# What is meant with "$df_x(h)$ is a linear function of $h$"?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, differential-topology

In Milnor's *Topology From the Differentiable Viewpoint*, the derivative of a smooth map $f: U\to V$  is defined as 
$$
\mathrm{d}f_x: \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}^l
$$
$$
h\mapsto \lim_{t\to0} \frac{f(x+th)-f(x)}{t}
$$
On the fifth page he remarks

> Clearly $\mathrm{d}f_x (h)$  is a linear function of $h$.

What does he mean here? This would require that $\mathrm{d} f_x (h_1+h_2)= \mathrm{d} f_x(h_1)+\mathrm{d} f_x(h_2)$, but this is does not seem to the case in general.

Comment: For differentiable functions, $\mathrm{d} f_x (h_1+h_2)= \mathrm{d} f_x(h_1)+\mathrm{d} f_x(h_2)$ is true in general. For differentiable $f$, $\mathrm{d}f_x(h)=J_x(h)$ where $J_x$ is the Jacobian at $x$.

Comment: $df_x(h)$ is just $D_h f (x)$, i.e. the directional derivative of $f$ at $x$ and in the direction of $h$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think Milnor means what he says: $df_x(h)$ is a linear function of $h$ (not of $f$, as @Jp McCarthy suggested). I think "clearly" is overstating the case, however.  In fact, the usual definition of what it means to say that $f$ is ***differentiable at $\boldsymbol x$*** is equivalent to the statement that the limit 
$$
\lim_{t\to0} \frac{f(x+th)-f(x)}{t}
$$
exists and depends linearly on $h$. Milnor's claim that this is the case relies on a theorem that a function of class $C^1$ (meaning that all first partial derivatives exist and are continuous) is differentiable at every point. This can be proved, for example, by using Taylor's theorem, or more directly by applying the fundamental theorem of calculus to the function $t\mapsto f(x+th)$.

Comment: Thank you I deleted my incorrect answer. I thought things were straightforward but then, as I said, I got confused. I appreciate your tone by the way.

Comment: @Jp McCarthy: You're welcome!